# Symfony - Entity with a unique value in two fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In my user entity, I have two fields (username and email) 
and I want them to be mutually unique. I put the Annotation « UniqueEntity » on the top of my entity class and a unique property on each field like this :

```
/**
* Class User
* @package App\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints={
* @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="app_user_email", columns="email"),
* @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="app_user_username", columns="username")
* })
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"})
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"})
*/
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
....

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Assert\Email
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Length(max=255, maxMessage="...")
 */
private $email;


....
}
```

In my database I can't have 2 identical email or username. This is a valid point. I want moreover that a value in one of the two fields is not found in one of the other two fields.

For example, if an entry in the User table has a specific email value, I do not want to be able to enter the same value in the username field for an other user.

What is the best way to do this ?

The purpose of all this is for a user to be able to authenticate with his username or email and if a mail for a user is equal to a username of another user it will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy, in your entity you can add a callback constraint

First add

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
```

and in your class add

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    if ($this->username == $this->email) {
        $context->buildViolation('The username can\'t be the email')
            ->atPath('username')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

check https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html for your symfony version

Comment: I'm not sure it can work and that it verifies that a username is not equal to an email on all the entries in the table 'User'.

Comment: you can add a check in the method to verify if the username is an email and add a violation